# How to connect to teiid VDB in python

Tags: python, teiid

I need to connect to teiid datasource in Python and execute procedure, are there any libraries to connect to teiid VDB?

Comment: Try with `psycopg2` ; [More](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241609?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 1):

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidDriver', 'jdbc:teiid:VDB@mm://hostname:port;version= ', [usename,password], r'PATH_TO_JAR_FILE\teiid-12.2.0-jdbc.jar',)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from testtable")
data = curs.fetchall()
```

This code worked connecting to teiid.